# Calling Instance of a Class

Tags: c++, class

I am wondering if someone could give me some guidance on how to call a class and execute a function.

Basically, I have a virtual bank program where I want to add and deposit money for the user.

I have created an instance of the bank called Bank bankCustomer1;

So then I have like this calling to access the bank for that instancce:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "bank.hpp"

int main(){
   bank bankCustomer1; 
   cout << "Let's save some money to bank" << endl;
   bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);
return 0;
}
```

Bank.hpp

```
#ifndef BANK_HPP
#define BANK_HPP
#include "bank.hpp"

#include <string>

class bank {
     private: savings = 0;
public:
    bank();

    void defaultsettings();
    bool addMoney(double money);
    void getSavings();
}
```

Bank.cpp

```
#include "bank.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bank.addMoney(double money){
      bool moneyAdded = true;

      if(money < 0){
           cout << "There has been an error" << endl;
           return false;
      }
      else{
           savings = savings + money; 
           return true;
      }

}

bank.getSavings(double money){
//Nothing has been added

}
```

However this is wrong and I dont know why. I get these errors:

```
 expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
     bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10).
```

Comment: I just wanted to write a comment but realized that there are too many inconsistencies in your code. Please clarify them before anyone is able to answer your question: How are `bank`, `Bank`, and `PiggiBank` related? Should the be the same class? A similar thing is happening with the function (`addMoney`, `adddepositMoney`, `depositMoney`). Your `savings` field has no data type. Is the dot in your function definition supposed to be a double colon (`PiggyBank::depositMoney`)?

Comment: There is no member called bankCustomer1.  Show us more of main.cpp.  You are instantisting incorrectly probably.

Comment: You've got the wrong syntax for defining a function and have missed off a return type, and you seem to have called the same function three different things, C++ won't fill in the gaps and function names are case sensitive.

Comment: I have added more code from the main program and fixed naming of the instances.

Comment: This is still just too broken to make any sort of useful comment, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I have added basically all the files

Comment: Change `bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);` to `bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);`

Comment: `bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);` -> `bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);` & `bank.addMoney(double money)` -> `bool bank::addMoney(double money)`.

Comment: redefinition of ‘class bank’ class bank when I change it to that name. previous definition of ‘class bank’ class bank{. So I tried to add header definitions and it didn't work gave an error.

Comment: bank.hpp should not include itself.

Comment: Ok fixed, so now it says this on header definition:  unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef BANK_H

Comment: Difficult to help with code that you have not posted.

Comment: I have updated bank.hpp code.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic understanding of C++ syntax and semantics seems mostly OK, with the following exceptions.

First, in main.cpp, you do this:

```
bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);
```

You do not need (and aren't allowed) to specify the class name when trying to access an object. You must do this instead:

```
bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);
```

This will call the `addMoney()` function on the `bankCustomer1` object. The compiler already knows that this object is of class `bank`.

Next up, in `bank.hpp`, you have this:

```
class bank {
    private: savings = 0;
```

You are trying to declare a private member variable. But you need to specify the type of the variable. In this case, you seem to want it to be of type `double`, so you need to do this:

```
class bank {
private:
    double savings = 0;
```

(Note that you don't need to write `private:` in front of every private member, so usually `private:` is put on its own line.)

Also in `bank.hpp`, you have the usual multiple inclusion guard at the top:

```
#ifndef BANK_HPP
#define BANK_HPP
```

but you forgot to close the `#ifndef` with an `#endif`. At the end of the file, you need:

```
#endif
```

However, and I'm sure someone will disagree here because it's not standard C++, I recommend using `#pragma once` instead of the classic inclusion guards. So instead of:

```
#ifndef BANK_HPP
#define BANK_HPP
// ...
#endif
```

I recommend you just use this at the beginning of headers:

```
#pragma once
```

Yes, it's not in the standard, but it's a de-facto standard supported by virtually every compiler.

Note that this line in `bank.hpp`:

```
#include "bank.hpp"
```

is not needed, and has no effect. You should delete it. A file should not include itself. If it weren't for the multiple inclusion guard, this would get you a compile error because you'd run into an infinite inclusion loop.

Next up, in `bank.cpp`, you have:

```
bank.addMoney(double money) {
```

This is the wrong syntax when trying to implement a member function. The syntax is:

```
return_type class_name::function_name(arguments)
```

So you need:

```
bool bank::addMoney(double money) {
```

Finally, you have declared a constructor and a function in the `bank.hpp` header that you didn't actually implement anywhere:

```
bank();
void defaultsettings();
```

You need to implement these too. You can do that in `bank.cpp`:

```
bank::bank()
{ /* ... */ }

void bank::defaultsettings()
{ /* ... */ }
```

Functions can instead be implemented inline inside the header instead of the `.cpp` file. Example:

```
class bank {
public:
    bank()
    { /* ... */ }

    // ...
};
```

This is usually done for very short functions.

And a final note: if you don't need any code in the constructor, you can actually completely omit it. The compiler will provide a default constructor for you that does nothing. So in this case, you can just delete `bank()` from the header file and don't need to implement it.

A suggestion though: in C++ (and most languages that have a similar class model), the convention is capitalize class names. So instead of `bank`, you should use `Bank`. This makes it easier to distinguish class names from variable names in code.

Comment: Could you look at the header guard in my bank.hpp please?

Comment: You are missing the #endif // and a ; after the class declaration.

Comment: Oh that was a silly mistake. So now I'm error free :) Now it just says:  undefined reference to bank::bank(). And then same thing for all my functions

Comment: @Nick I assumed you just omitted these functions to keep your code shorter. You need to implement these in the same manner you implemented `addMoney()`. I'll update the answer then to include these.

Comment: So I got that added to the bank.cpp and still the same thing. It actually gives me the error on the main.cpp. But referencing the bank.cpp file. Gave me an error anywhere I called like bankccustomer1.addMoney();

Comment: @Nick Did you compile bank.cpp? It sound like you didn't compile it. What are you using to develop this? Have you added the bank.cpp file to the project? Or are you building manually from the command line? In that case, have you added bank.cpp to the compilation command?

Comment: I'm using a complier that runs all of the files in the folder.

Comment: @Nick Well, I don't know then. I have no idea what you're using. If you compile and link the files correctly, you will get no errors.

Comment: I got it working another small error again (get you every time). Can I not change a private parameter in a function?

Comment: @Nick You mean a private member. Private members of a class are only accessible by the functions of that class. Other functions have no access.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can find lots of tutorials of.

You need to specify the return type of each function firstly, secondly you need to specify the namespace of the function.

Like this:

```
#include "bank.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool Bank::addMoney(double money){
      bool moneyAdded = true;

      if(money < 0){
           cout << "There has been an error" << endl;
           return false;
      }
      else{
           savings = savings + money; 
           return true;
      }

}

void Bank::getSavings(double money){
//Nothing has been added

}
```

getSavings sounds like it should return a double though

And when you call the member function from an instance in main, you don't need to specify that it's a Bank-object, "it already understands that it is one" since you created it before using it. So instead of

```
bank.bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);
```

You call the function like this:

```
bankCustomer1.addMoney(10);
```

Comment: ***you can find lots of tutorials*** I would recommend reading a c++ good book.

Comment: If he was learning from a book, he wouldn't be asking the question here.

Comment: I think the problem is the OP is trying to learn from online videos instead of a book.

Comment: I'm assuming that won't be happening any time soon however holistic and better a book is, the option can still be ignored. It's not my problem though, I just don't like to give non-answers to questions.